# Why are reference types not destroyed immediately like value types?

Tags: types, reference, heap-memory, stack-memory

Many tutorials say that reference types are created on the heap and can only be destroyed when the last reference disappears. On the contrary, value types are created on the stack and destroyed automatically right after they go out of scope. This information can be found in many literature.

But I couldn't figure out the reason why reference types are not just destroyed such as in value type case.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/139010?

Comment: Ok I know how stack and heap works. My question is WHY? What is the reason? What is the benefit not to delete heap just after as in stack?

Comment: Given that you're asking this question it sounds like you don't fully see the difference yet. **How does the system know when it's safe to delete objects from the heap?**

Answer (score 0):

> Many tutorials say that reference types ... can only be destroyed when the last reference disappears.

How else do you know when a reference type has gone out of scope?

Comment: It sounds like you're imagining some alternative mechanism which would allow reference types to be trivially deallocated. Is that right?

Comment: No I'm wondering why deallocation on the heap not that easy as in the stack. They are both in the RAM.